# Can you see the exact http request string in chrome

Tags: http, google-chrome-devtools, httprequest

I am programming an HTTP request parser and I would like to see the string Chrome sends whenever a resource is requested (that may be a website or content on the website). I know that you can go into the Chrome developer tools under the network tab and then see all the details about the requests sent. However, these details are already parsed into categories and I would like a raw string representation of the HTTP request. Is there any way to get just that and, if not, could you recommend any tool or website to get a bunch of dummy HTTP requests to debug my parser?

Comment: Try an external tool like Fiddler, Charles, Postman.

Comment: @wOxxOm Fiddler seems ideal for that, thank you very much. But I guess there is no way acquiring it from the chrome devtools directly?

Comment: The only [semi] built-in facility is probably `chrome://net-export`

Comment: @wOxxOm Alright, had a look at this and it appears to log the parameters, but no the whole request as a raw string. But I tried Fiddler and that works awesomely. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Was this about a POST request's body? If so you can simply click `view source` to the right of `Request Payload`.

Comment: @wOxxOm No I just need a bunch of dummy requests to debug my parser and I wanted to acquired a wide variety of requests by looking at raw request strings Chrome sends to the servers. However, the information about the request is (most of the times fortunately) always already parsed into parameters. Just gonna use your provided information to answer my question if anyone should ever have the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in function to acquire the raw http request string in Chrome. Request parameters can either be optained by using the network tab in the developer tools or by using `chrome://net-export`.

However, external tools such as [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) can obtain the raw http requests send and responses recieved by your computer. Just select a request on the left and the raw output format.